# Issues with @font-face on Firefox 3.6.13?

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

In the last day or two, Firefox rolled out its update to version 3.6.13. I restarted my browser today and now my sites that use an OTF font-face are not rendering the text with the custom font. I should note that it had worked fine in the previous version of Firefox and continues to work fine in other browser platforms that support @font-face and OTF font formats.

Anyone else having this issue and is there a solution?

Thanks!

Example: [Example of @font-face rendering issue](http://blog.festoolusa.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using Paul Irish's bulletproof @font-face syntax

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'FontName';
      src: url('FontName.eot');
      src: local('☺'),
             url('FontName.otf') format('opentype');
    }
```

or you can use the [Font Squirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Comment: Sah-weet! Thx shooter. The Squirrel generator converted my licensed OTF to the other formats and generated the proper CSS markup. Perfect, easy solution. Dig it. Thanks!